# How to get the List Index of a List Tuple element

Tags: c#, wpf, tuples

I have created a List Tuple String int like this:

```
public static List<Tuple<string, int>> myGrid = new List<Tuple<string, int>>();

myGrid.Add(new Tuple<string, int>("Alpha", 159));
```

I have done so, because I need to work with index in my code.

How to get the List index of Tuple Item1 or Item2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var indexByItem1 = myGrid.FindIndex(0, t => t.Item1 == "Alpha");
var indexByItem2 = myGrid.FindIndex(0, t => t.Item2 == 159);
```

See [this interactive fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JWhUte).